# Xamarin Updates Forced?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've detected a pattern where I seem to be unable to connect Visual Studio (2012) to the Mac build server whenever a new Xamarin update is available. The Connect to Mac dialogue just displays the message "An unexpected error occurred while trying to log in. Please try again." (SSH Fingerprint is successfully retrieved.) Restarting Xamarin and Visual Studio, restarting the build server, etc. doesn't seem to make a difference.

I've specifically documented for my own benefit this happening four times now, and I believe it's happened before as well. As soon as I install all Visual Studio updates and all updates on the build server, everything works again. I've experienced this on both the Stable and Beta releases.

Is it an odd coincidence, or is there a systematic reason for why this seems to happen so consistently?

Comment: The connection is extremely easily broken. I may get connection one day, the next day it just doesn't work. And their way of not showing errors is infuriating. Even the logs don't help. So it might be a coincidence, I've reverted to doing all iOS things on OS X since Xamarin iOS on VS just doesn't work.

Comment: What's crazy is I've actually experienced very consistent connections to the mac build server at least with the latest ten or so releases. Even if I get a rare disconnect, simply reconnecting usually works first time. It's just odd that when I hit a serious connection issue that I can't fix, it's been when a Xamarin update is available. And then updating totally fixes the problem. Again, maybe just a delusion on my part though.

Comment: I just want to reiterate that I've seen this behavior repeated on the two most recent Xamarin updates as well. It could be something about my system, but it really seems like a forced update. Getting pretty frustrated.